# DAX to calculate consecutive days worked by employee between days worked and not worked

Tags: dax

I have been working on this problem for a while and have been able to get to this point.  Since Power BI is based on columns, it has proven very challenging to get to the end result needed.

I need to calculate the number of consecutive days worked between the last day the employee did not work and the next day the colleague did not work.  The final outcome would be to determine those employees that work 6 or more days in a row.

Data has all dates, dates worked, count of days worked and an index for sorting.  I have tried a number of measures and calculated columns that are based on the dates; however, this needs to be by employee and then calculated between the days not worked.  The desired out come is in the image linked.
[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXUyO.png)

Have tried various versions of the following without a good result.  Can provide a test .pbix if needed.

(based on similar data set - different column names)

```
DaysWorked_cumulative = 
   var start_date = min('work_data'[Date])
   var end_dates = all('work_data'[Date])
   var dateswithwork = CALCULATETABLE(values('work_data'[Days Worked]), ALLSELECTED())
   var dateswithoutwork = except(end_dates, dateswithwork)
   var nearestgap = maxx(FILTER(dateswithoutwork, 'work_data'[Date] <= start_date), 'work_data'[Date])
   var result = int(start_date - nearestgap))
return
   result
```

Also tried this - did not get desired outcome

```
Consecutive Days Between Blanks = 
   VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE (Employees[Date worked]) 
   VAR LastBlankDate = CALCULATE (MAXX (FILTER (Employees, ISBLANK ([Count])), Employees[Date worked]),    Employees[Date worked] < CurrentDate) 
   VAR NextBlankDate = CALCULATE (MINX (FILTER (Employees, ISBLANK ([Count])), Employees[Date worked]), Employees[Date worked] > CurrentDate) 
    RETURN DATEDIFF (LastBlankDate, NextBlankDate, DAY)
```